# Call second endpoint with retrofit if a condition is true, using RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

Im trying to chain a second call to a endpoint if a condition is true, this condition has nothing to do with the first endpoint call. This is how i have it so far:

```
retrofitService.endpoint1()
            .subscribe(response1 -> {
                    doStuff(response1);
                    if (condition){
                        retrofitService.endpoint2()
                                .subscribe(response2 -> {
                                doStuff(response2)
                                 });
                    }
              });
```

Is there an operator i can use to avoid doing the if and the second call in the first's call subscriber?

Answer (score 0):

I would use filter
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html

cheers
Wojtek

About your comment

do like that:

```
retrofitService.endpoint1()
    .filter(condition)
    .subscribe(response1 -> {
                    retrofitService.endpoint2()
                        .subscribe(response2 -> {
                                    doStuff(response2)
                                                });

              });
```

Comment: this would work if the second api call used the results from the first one, but im trying to call the second regardless of what the first one returned but conditioned by a boolean.